# Sorting the SortedDictionary keys using for each

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, sorteddictionary

```
Good afternoon. I have a strange problem. When iterating through the list, SortedDictionary does not recognize the key. Namely, it gives out that the key was not found. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
```

Moreover, an error is issued only when more than 2 elements are added to the list. At the same time, if 3 elements are wrong on the 1st, if 5 then on the 1st and 3rd, 4 again on the 1st.

```
public: Collections::Generic::SortedDictionary<Product_for_sale^, int> products;
 
void Score:: setProductsLabel() {
    int y = 50;
    productLabels.Clear();
    for each (Product_for_sale ^ key in products.Keys) {
        
        String^ product_by_score = "";
        System::Windows::Forms::Label^ info = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        
            if (products[key] > 0) {
                product_by_score = key->getName() + "       |       " + products[key] +
                    "        |        " + key->getFullPrice() * products[key] + "\n";
                info->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
            }
            else {
                info->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::PaleGreen;
                product_by_score = key->getName() + "       |       " + "СОБРАНО" +
                    "        |        " + key->getFullPrice() * products[key] + "\n";
            }
        
        
        
        info->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.00F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
            static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
        info->AutoSize = true;
        info->Location = System::Drawing::Point(10, y);
        info->Name = L"label4";
        info->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 25);
        info->TabIndex = 2;
        info->Text = product_by_score;
        productLabels.Add(key,info );
 
        y += 30;
    }
    
    
 
}
 
//реализация сравнения в классе Product_for_sale
 
int Product_for_sale::equals(Product_for_sale^ pfs) {
    if (this->name->Equals(pfs->getName())) {
        return 0;
    }
    else return 1;
}
int  Product_for_sale::CompareTo(Object^ obj){
 
    if (obj->GetType() == Product_for_sale::typeid) {
        Product_for_sale^ product = dynamic_cast<Product_for_sale^>(obj);
 
        return equals(product);
    }
    else return 1;
//  throw gcnew ArgumentException("object is not a Score");
}
```

The error crashes precisely on the expression products[key] with the key itself, you can work and get data from the object.

I checked the occupancy of the list at the entrance, everything is correct, both the key and the value. And again, if there are 2 pairs in the list, everything works without problems.

Comment: CompareTo() is not properly implemented, it won't return a negative value.

Comment: why?  if names are equal was return 0. where mistake?

Comment: Follow the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-7.0), focus on the documentation for the return value.  This bug was caused by writing the equals() function, best to get rid of it.

Comment: Yes you right, this decision is true `int  Product_for_sale::CompareTo(Object^ obj){

 if (obj->GetType() == Product_for_sale::typeid) {
  Product_for_sale^ product = dynamic_cast<Product_for_sale^>(obj);
  
  return name->CompareTo(product->getName());
  
 }
 else return 1;

}`

Answer (score -1):

In the provided equals method, it returns 0 if the names are equal and 1 if they are not. This doesn't follow the standard convention. Replace the whole snippet as below:

```cpp
int Product_for_sale::CompareTo(Object^ obj) {
    if (obj->GetType() == Product_for_sale::typeid) {
        Product_for_sale^ product = dynamic_cast<Product_for_sale^>(obj);
        return name->CompareTo(product->getName());
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```